# Display sum of inner joined tables exluding NULL sums

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT 
t1.aID, t1.firstname, t1.lastname,
SUM(t2.price) AS sumsales
FROM t3
  INNER JOIN t1
    ON t3.aID = t1.aID
  INNER JOIN t2
    ON t3.wID = t2.wID
GROUP BY (t1.aID, t1.firstname, t1.lastname)
ORDER BY sumsales DESC
```

How can I remove all the rows with a null sumsales column from the results of this oracle SQL query?

I tried

```
WHERE sumsales IS NOT NULL
```

above *GROUP BY* but it did not work.

Replacing the null with a 0 would also be acceptable but I could not figure out how to replace null during/after selection.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: user nvl function on i.e. nvl( sum(t2.price), 0), this should work

Comment: Did you tried `with abc AS (...) SELECT * FROM abc WHERE sumsales IS NOT NULL;` or `having` clause?

Comment: @VinitPrajapati Thank you very much that worked for setting the null to 0

Answer (score 2):

Since `sumsales` is an aggregated value, you should use [having](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause:

```
SELECT 
t1.aID, t1.firstname, t1.lastname,
SUM(t2.price) AS sumsales
FROM t3
  INNER JOIN t1
    ON t3.aID = t1.aID
  INNER JOIN t2
    ON t3.wID = t2.wID
GROUP BY (t1.aID, t1.firstname, t1.lastname)
HAVING sumsales IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY sumsales DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `NULL` value with `0` using `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT t1.aID, t1.firstname, t1.lastname,
       COALESCE(SUM(t2.price), 0) AS sumsales
FROM t3 INNER JOIN
     t1
     ON t3.aID = t1.aID INNER JOIN
     t2
     ON t3.wID = t2.wID
GROUP BY t1.aID, t1.firstname, t1.lastname
ORDER BY sumsales DESC;
```

Alternatively, if you don't want `NULL` values for `sumsales`, you can just filter out `NULL` prices *before* the aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.aID, t1.firstname, t1.lastname,
       SUM(t2.price AS sumsales
FROM t3 INNER JOIN
     t1
     ON t3.aID = t1.aID INNER JOIN
     t2
     ON t3.wID = t2.wID
WHERE t2.price IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t1.aID, t1.firstname, t1.lastname
ORDER BY sumsales DESC;
```

This would typically be the most efficient approach.  Note that you cannot use aggregation functions in a `WHERE` clause, but you can put them in a `HAVING` clause as @NirLevy suggests.

It is also unclear what the join to `t3` is accomplishing, unless you have it only for filtering purposes.  The code is not using any columns from that table.